# How to disable Safari 7 kerning/ligatures to make text look like it did in Safari 6 or Chrome

Tags: css, safari, kerning, ligature

This test shows that Safari 7 squeezes text together, unlike Safari 6, Chrome (by default), and Firefox: https://writerduet.com/test.html

It's very important for my project that text line up the same across browsers. Safari 7 is radically different from 6.1 because it turned on kerning/ligatures by default, and I can't figure out how to turn them off. I played with `text-rendering`, `font-feature-settings`, and `-webkit-font-feature-settings` CSS properties to no avail.

I found that if I set the following CSS property (in Test #3), Chrome has the same behavior as Safari 7, but none of my attempts to reverse that setting resulted in Safari not doing the line squeezing:

```css
-webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1;
```

I've spent many hours searching and guessing, so thank you very much in advance for any solutions!

This is not a duplicate of the other issue referenced since the solution there does not work. I don't actually know what the bug is here in Safari, so I can't describe it better.